# How to dynamically build Postgres query from API parameters in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm looking for a way to dynamically build a SQL query for an unknown number of API parameters that may come back. As a simple example, consider the following query:

```js
router.get("/someEndpoint", authorizationFunction, async (req, res) => {
  let sql = `
    SELECT *
    FROM some_table
    WHERE username = $1
      ${req.query.since !== undefined ? "AND hire_date >= $2" : ""}
  `

  const results = await pool.query(sql, [req.query.user, req.query.since]);
}
```

where `pool` is defined as

```js
const Pool = require("pg").Pool; 
const pool = new Pool({<connection parameters>});
```

The problem I'm having is that if `req.query.since` is not provided, then the SQL query only requires a single bound parameter (`$1`). This is presented as an error that says `bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 1`. Since I don't know which parameters a user will provide until the time of the query, I'm under the impression that I need to provide all possible value, and let the query figure it out.

I've seen a lot of posts that point to [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) as a solution, but I'm wondering if that's necessary. Is there a way that I can solve this with my current setup? Perhaps I'm thinking about the problem incorrectly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Add a trivial expression text that contains `$2` and evaluates to `true` instead of `""`, for example

```sql
  SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE username = $1 AND 
  ${req.query.since !== undefined ? " hire_date >= $2": " (true or $2 = $2)"}
```

The planner will remove it anyway. Added `true or` just in case `$2` is null.
Still it would be cleaner like this

```js
if (req.query.since !== undefined)
{
  let sql = `SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE username = $1 AND hire_date >= $2`;
  const results = await pool.query(sql, [req.query.user, req.query.since]);
}
else
{
  let sql = `SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE username = $1`;
  const results = await pool.query(sql, [req.query.user]);
}
```

What about SQLi risk BTW?